# getting the first and last images (addresses) of the code

Tags: llvm, memory-address

I am trying to grab the addresses that associated with the start of the source code and the one at the end. I tried to do it using LLVM, Clang but I could not.
Is there a way to get the memory addresses that associated of each line in the source code?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are several possibilities:

- You can use debug information for this. Note, however, that this
  information might not be precise for optimized code
- Alternatively,
  you can use special linker script which will insert two symbols
  before and after all the code in the code section.

Comment: Anton Thank you so much for helping me. I just not that good in compiler, I am using Clang for get the debug information. I used this command:

clang++ -S -emit-llvm helloworld.cpp 
opt -print-dbginfo helloworld.s

However, It gives me nothing!

Comment: add -g to produce debug info